# Add only if div doesn't have class on it

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement

My problem is that I want score to be added only when the user clicks the `div` and the `div` doesn't have class `selected` or `wrong` on it. In simpler words, if class already exists on the `div`, I don't want the score to be added. Right now it works fine but it keeps adding score if the user keeps clicking on the same `div`.

Sorry for the incomplete code(this is part of pretty long jQuery game) but any guidance will be helpful!

**JQuery**

```
if ($(this).attr("selected") == "selected") {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    var score = parseInt($("#score").html());
    score += 20;
    $("#score").html(score);
} else {
    $(this).addClass("wrong");
    var score = parseInt($("#score").html());
    score -= 10;
    $("#score").html(score);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.hasClass()` as shown:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('wrong') && !$(this).hasClass('selected'))
{
  if ($(this).attr("selected") == "selected") {
     $(this).addClass("selected");
     var score = parseInt($("#score").html());
     score += 20;
     $("#score").html(score);
  } else {
     $(this).addClass("wrong");
     var score = parseInt($("#score").html());
     score -= 10;
     $("#score").html(score);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine :) Thank you so much! will accept it when I can

Comment: @imbondbaby....just check whether you want `||` or `&&` condition as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use removeClass to remove that already exist:

```
if ($(this).attr("selected") == "selected") {
    $(this).removeClass();// remove already added class if there
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    var score = parseInt($("#score").html());
    score += 20;
    $("#score").html(score);
} else {
    $(this).removeClass();// remove already added class if there
    $(this).addClass("wrong");
    var score = parseInt($("#score").html());
    score -= 10;
    $("#score").html(score);
}
```